# Are there any more optimal tactile alphabets than Braille?

Tags: english, french, alphabets, readability

Sorry if this is the wrong stackexchange to ask this.

Consider how QWERTY was the first keyboard layout, but isn't nearly optimal (e.g. Dvorak is much better and used overwhelmingly by top speed-typers).

Braille was created a long time ago by the French (who didn't even properly account for "w"). Sure, it's the main standard used today for tactile alphabets. But my question is if anyone has made a more optimal tactile alphabet since then? E.g. a tactile alphabet that is more robust to misreading, or allows for faster reading.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Tactile alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactile_alphabet) links to articles about some other systems, but doesn't cite any analysis or comparison.